# Java Memory Deallocation

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I am writing a game in Java and after monitoring it for a while throught the Windows Task Manager, I have noticed some memory leaks, as every time I reloaded a level the memory used went up by 2 Megabytes. After searching in my game code for a while I reached the conclusion that the memory leak was created by  some ArrayList objects I was using to store other game objects such as enemies.

So I created a new Java project to run some tests.
Let's say that I have a class called Test

```
public class Test 
{
  private int i;
  public Test()
  {
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

That's a pretty simple class, containing only one integer. So I guess an object of such a class would consume around 4 bytes of memory.

After that I created an array list of Test objects, and I filled it with 10.000 objects.

```
ArrayList<Test> testList = new ArrayList<Test>();
for (int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
   testList.add(new Test());
}
```

This increased my memory usage a lot as i noticed through the Task Manager, as it should.
The problem though is that even if i clear the whole array list using

```
testList.clear();
```

The memory used still remains the same, let's say 40k. **My question is how do I manage to deallocate items in an arraylist that I no longer need?** I know java is using automatic garbage collection  and in order for an object to be elligible for garbage collection there must be no references to it from other objects, but I don't understand why it is not deallocating those Test objects.

Even if i use System.gc(); there seems to be no difference in memory used.

Comment: Java doesn't free memory back to the OS for performance reasons; the number you care about is the amount of memory free within Java. See also [`Runtime.freeMemory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are getting is the memory allocated by the JVM, not the actual memory usage.

This is what I use to monitor actual memory usage:

```
int mb = 1024 * 1024;

String memory = "Total Memory: " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / mb) + "MB\nFree Memory: "
            + (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / mb) + "MB\nUsed Memory: "
            + ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / mb) + "MB";
```

You should see the used memory going up slowly and falling down whenever the garbage collector is called

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.